# Make Clustered Google Map

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, google-maps

I've a Google Map having Multiple Markers with the Lines drawn between them. I want this map to be clustered.

I've tried the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=map_init"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function InitializeMap() {
            var ltlng = [];

            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392498333333332,71.69455666666666));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392564999999998,71.69445666666667));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.400855,71.66181499999999));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392459999999996,71.69463));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392541666666663,71.69443333333334));

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                //center: latlng,
                center: ltlng[0],
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            for (var i = 0; i < ltlng.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                    (
                    {
                        // position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                        position: ltlng[i],
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Click me'
                    }
                    );
            }        


               var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: ltlng,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#4986E7',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

            flightPath.setMap(map);

  this.markers = data.map((location) => {
    if (location.location === null) return
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: location.location.coordinates[0], lng: location.location.coordinates[1]},
      map: this.map
    });
    return marker
  });
  const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

        }

        window.onload = InitializeMap;

    </script>
    <h2>Creating Your First Google Map Demo:</h2>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; top: 68px; left: 172px; position: absolute; height: 500px">
    </div>
```

I've gone through the following:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering
[Google Map Clusterer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905500/google-map-clusterer)

[Google Map Clusterer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905500/google-map-clusterer)

but it's not working.

Please help me resolve this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final answer:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=map_init"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function InitializeMap() {
            var ltlng = [];    

            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392498333333332,71.69455666666666));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392564999999998,71.69445666666667));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.400855,71.66181499999999));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392459999999996,71.69463));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(29.392541666666663,71.69443333333334));

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                //center: latlng,
                center: ltlng[0],
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var markers = []; 
            for (var i = 0; i < ltlng.length; i++)
            {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                    (
                    {
                        // position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                        position: ltlng[i],
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Click me'
                    }
                );
                 markers.push(marker);
            }                

          var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: ltlng,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#4986E7',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

            flightPath.setMap(map);



            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

        }

        window.onload = InitializeMap;

    </script>
    <h2>Creating Your First Google Map Demo:</h2>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; top: 68px; left: 172px; position: absolute; height: 500px">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I added the array of markers and saved all the markers in the array while looping. then used this array of markers in calling Clustering Method.